# Refused to load the image '<URL>'

Tags: html, css, image, content-security-policy, src

I am trying to load images in my index.ejs as bellow

> ```
>       <img src="<%=imageBaseUrl+movie.poster_path %>" alt="">
> ```

imageBaseUrl set as:

> imageBaseUrl="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";

**But I am getting error as Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".**
[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEqqY.png)

What should I do to resolve this error ?

Comment: Remove this 
Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'

Comment: This must be set in the server, serving the HTML page. http response headers are generally use to set CSP.

Comment: Adjust CSP as `img-src 'self' data: https://image.tmdb.org` to prevent blocking images from `https://image.tmdb.org`

Comment: Why is this down voted? I have the exakt same question with the same API in an ejs-file. And I don't know what CSP is and how to set/adjust it.

Comment: So I figured out that I use "helmet" in my Node-express app. When I comment out the line where I set app.use(helmet()) everything loads. The question is now how to use helmet and make this work. Still don't understand why this question was down voted.